# CQ5 querying node which has access for a particular user

Tags: aem

In geometrix site if I need to get the results for page which has only user X has access

Following query pulls all the records, but I need to restrict for only X user

http://myserver.com:4502/bin/querybuilder.feed?orderby=%40jcr%3acontent%2fjcr%3acreated&orderby.index=true&orderby.sort=desc&path=%2fcontent%2fgeometrixx%2fen&type=cq%3aPage

What are the parameters that need to be included in the url

Answer (score 1):

[ACL mechanism](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/AccessControl), responsible for authorization (deciding if a user has access to a resource) is quite complicated. Privileges are inherited from ancestor nodes, there are groups (and a group may be member of another group), etc. That's why **it is not possible to write a query that will list nodes available for a particular user**.

However, you may create a resource resolver working on behalf of any user and use it to query the repository - you'll get only resources available to the resource resolver "owner". Example:

```
final String user = "my-user";
final String query = "SELECT * FROM [cq:Page] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/content/geometrixx/en]) ORDER BY [jcr:created]";

Map<String, Object> authInfo = new HashMap<String, Object>();
authInfo.put(ResourceResolverFactory.USER_IMPERSONATION, user);
ResourceResolver resolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(authInfo);
Iterator<Resource> result = resolver.findResources(query, "JCR-SQL2");
```